# ExecJS::RuntimeError in ChatRooms#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am having this error. I have already installed nodejs and also added gem'therubyracer'.

> ActionView::Template::Error (SyntaxError: [stdin]:21:3: unexpected ():

```
<%= csp_meta_tag %>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

> app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__3921329476922966565_70164612108380'

However, after I add this block of code in my rooms.coffee file, I get the error:

```
$('#new_message').submit(e) ->
    $this = $(this)
    textarea = $this.find('#message_body')
    if $.trim(textarea.val()).length > 1
    App.global_chat.send_message textarea.val(),
    messages.data('chat-room-id')
    textarea.val('')
    e.preventDefault()
    return false
```

I am currently using Linux mint.

Comment: Please post the error message in the question, not as a link

Comment: Is the above information useful enough?